# IE7 CSS padding Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, padding

my website for the most part works well, but I have one small problem with the Site-Title padding in IE7.  In all other browsers there is sufficient padding around the main logo. See top-left logo at website: http://alt.beaufortmusicfestival.com  In IE7 there is no padding between the word "Festival" and the top edge of the main nav bar.  When I mod the code it changes in all but IE7 in which there is no difference at all.  Please see the following:

```
#site-title{
 padding:0px 0 0px 0;      **** this is the code that i am refering to. ****
}
```

Is there something I am missing here?  I know IE 7 is quite querky.  This css code is located in a file called ie.css and is called as a conditional css file in my header, which seems to be working OK at the moment.  It's just that IE doesn't seem to recognize any changes to the padding-bottom code.  Please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: It's best if you reduce your example to only the relevant code, and include some html so that it becomes a short and working example. That way we can help you a lot better, and this question will also be of use to future visitors (because eventually your link may change/die and your site will get fixed/changed).

Comment: Changing it to `padding:0 0 10px 0;` in IE7 adds padding below that `div` for me. Keep in mind that `core.css` is overwriting `ie.css`'s attributes, so you may need to use `!important`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try specifically for IE7

```
*:first-child+html #site-title {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

Comment: IE7 can be applied much more trivially like this: #site-title { *padding-bottom: 25px; }

Comment: Caligula thank you so much for your answer.  It worked very well.  I am not familiar with this so I need to read up on its use.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
#site-title{
 padding:0px 0 0px 0\9; for ie 8 ,also ie9 in some cases  
 padding:0px 0 0px 0!ihateie; exactly can be anything (string)
}
```

I hope this could help you :)